# How to split columns of a CSV file into separate files?

Tags: text-processing, awk, python, perl

I have csv file namely `list.csv` as shown below,

```
Pcissicola19,cissicola39,12xbauhiniae
BGDHLHFA_02833,DGDFDEGP_00879,POPGJMOL_04119
BGDHLHFA_01427,DGDFDEGP_03106,POPGJMOL_01558
BGDHLHFA_01618,DGDFDEGP_02529,POPGJMOL_04348
BGDHLHFA_01349,DGDFDEGP_02811,POPGJMOL_04175
BGDHLHFA_01734,DGDFDEGP_04039,POPGJMOL_04234
BGDHLHFA_00509,DGDFDEGP_02546,POPGJMOL_00085
BGDHLHFA_04577,DGDFDEGP_04242,POPGJMOL_00124
```

I need to print all the column (except first field of each column) separately into a new file named by the first field of each column. The expected output is as follows,

Pcissicola19.txt

```
BGDHLHFA_02833
BGDHLHFA_01427
BGDHLHFA_01618
BGDHLHFA_01349
BGDHLHFA_01734
BGDHLHFA_00509
BGDHLHFA_04577
```

cissicola39.txt

```
DGDFDEGP_00879
DGDFDEGP_03106
DGDFDEGP_02529
DGDFDEGP_02811
DGDFDEGP_04039
DGDFDEGP_02546
DGDFDEGP_04242
```

12xbauhiniae.txt

```
POPGJMOL_04119
POPGJMOL_01558
POPGJMOL_04348
POPGJMOL_04175
POPGJMOL_04234
POPGJMOL_00085
POPGJMOL_00124
```

I can print each column by using following command
`awk -F "," '{print $1}' list.csv` , but it is not serving my purpose in terms of saving file based on the first field and removing the first field in all the new files. Please help me to automate the process.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Can use a combination of **bash** with **awk**:

  ```
  for n in 1 2 3; do awk -F "," "{if (NR!=1) {print \$$n}}" list.scv > $(awk -F "," "{if (NR==1) {print \$$n}}" list.scv) ; done
  ```
- **Example:**
  [image]

Comment: this will fail if header fields were contain whitespaces; also you will need to first know how many columns your input file has. also in case header column were same for two or more columns only the last column having that same header will be written to file and old columns will be truncated;

Comment: This has several issues in addition to those raised by @αғsнιη including having to call awk 6 times (twice per column), puting the condition inside the action part of each awk script instead of in the condition part, and letting the value of a shell variable expand to become part of the awk script (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for how to really do that). It's simply the wrong approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{ split($0, tmp, ","); next }
              { for(col=1; col<=NF; col++){ print $col >>tmp[col]; close(tmp[col])} }' infile
```

In *`NR==1{ split($0, tmp, ","); next }`*; where `NR` in *awk* represent the total ***N***umber of ***R***ecords read/seen so far; so for the first line *NR* would be `1` and we are checking it with *`NR==1`*, if it's first line then its following block will be executed and we do [**split()**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) that line into pieces separated by a comma `,` and store the pieces in array `tmp`. and read `next` line;

In the second block we loop over the ***N***umber of ***F***ields in the current input record and print (append) the corresponding column by `$col` into the related fileName from the `tmp` array where the **key** is same with that column number.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk to manage large numbers of open files if you have more than about 15 columns (or any awk if fewer than that):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        out[i] = $i ".txt"
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $i > out[i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk list.csv
```

```
$ head *.txt
==> 12xbauhiniae.txt <==
POPGJMOL_04119
POPGJMOL_01558
POPGJMOL_04348
POPGJMOL_04175
POPGJMOL_04234
POPGJMOL_00085
POPGJMOL_00124

==> Pcissicola19.txt <==
BGDHLHFA_02833
BGDHLHFA_01427
BGDHLHFA_01618
BGDHLHFA_01349
BGDHLHFA_01734
BGDHLHFA_00509
BGDHLHFA_04577

==> cissicola39.txt <==
DGDFDEGP_00879
DGDFDEGP_03106
DGDFDEGP_02529
DGDFDEGP_02811
DGDFDEGP_04039
DGDFDEGP_02546
DGDFDEGP_04242
```

otherwise with any awk for any number of columns:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        out[i] = $i ".txt"
        printf "" > out[i]
        close(out[i])
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $i >> out[i]
        close(out[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `bash` and `cut` and `tr`

```
#!/bin/bash

id=0
while read filename; do
  id=$((id+1))
  tail -n +2 list | cut -d"," -f $id >> "$filename"
done < <(head -1 list.csv | tr "," "\n")
```